# Running old Directx7 game

Tags: gaming, directx

I have an old pc game that requires DirectX 7 and Windows 98/2000. When I try running it on Windows 7, it doesn't work.

Where can I find the DirectX 7 installation and will it allow me to install it on Windows 7? If you have any other idea of how to run this game, I'll be happy to hear them.

Comment: What game is it actually?

Comment: It's a space shooter i programmed :)

Comment: WIndows 7 comes with DirectX 11. You can't install older versions.

Comment: Rebuild your software to work with a newer version of DirectX

Comment: I can't rebuild the software with newer Directx because it's not the same interface at all.

Comment: DirectX 7 is not compatible with Windows 7.  Windows 7 doesn't come with DirectX 11, It comes with DirectX 10, 11 is Windows 8.0 and 8.1; 12 is Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound My Windows 7 has DirectX11. https://i.imgur.com/c8KgHrz.png

Comment: @DavidPostill - Microsoft Trickery; 11.1 is buitl-in 11.2 is not; 11.2 brought new hardware features which are not compatible with 11.1; I confused myself with Vista's 11.0 and people complaining they couldn't get DX11 on XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several solutions are worth investigating:

- Try to run in in Compatibility mode with Windows XP (this usually works).
- Check: Does the game support other GFx engine like OpenGL (does it have any openGL files)
- Check: Is the game able to run in software rendering (like good old UT99)
- If the game support STEAM, tell it through that to run in DX7 mode (Open Steam
  --> "My Games" --> right-click the game which needs to be reconfigured, select "Properties",  click the "Set launch options..." button, Add the DirectX level launch option of -DX7.

And no, you cannot install the old DX7 on post-Vista OS.